# Nesting parameters in --build-arg of docker build command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

lets start by example.
I have a simple Dockerfile:

```
ARG arg1
ARG arg2
RUN echo "$arg1 $arg2"
```

And what i expect when i call the command

```
docker build --build-arg arg1=abc --build-arg arg2=${arg1} .
```

Is that i got the **abc abc** as the outbut, but i got **abc**.
So is the result that i want possible? And how can I achieve it?

Comment: Does `arg2` have to be set at build time, or can it be set in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be set at build time. Most times it will be using default value, but it should be modifiable and then it should allow to do something like arg2=somedata${anotherArgument}somedata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your `Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine
ARG arg1
ARG arg2
RUN 

echo "$arg1 ${arg2:-$arg1}"
```

You can now call it like this:

`docker build --build-arg arg1=abc --build-arg arg2= .`

output:

```
...truncated...
Step 4/4 : RUN echo "$arg1 ${arg2:-$arg1}"
 ---> Running in e65458b9ba6e
abc abc
```

or like this:

`docker build --build-arg arg1=abc --build-arg arg2=override .`

output:

```
...truncated...
Step 4/4 : RUN echo "$arg1 ${arg2:-$arg1}"
 ---> Running in e65458b9ba6e
abc override
```

---

(old answer)

Based on the little info you've provided. I would say:

```
arg1=abc; docker build --build-arg arg1=$arg1 --build-arg arg2=$arg1
```

should give you what you want.

Comment: It's good point, but in my case it will not work. I'll try to give more details.
In most cases there will be used default arg1 and arg2 values. But user should be allowed to modify these parameters and user can do it from the GUI, but these arguments are always passed by the --build-arg parameter even if parameter is unchanged. So there can be a case when user change only arg1 but not arg2 and in  that case arg2 should use value from arg1. This is quite generic and from bash i only call the script, i cant set the environment variables :(

Comment: @JanNowak i updated my answer to fit your new parameters. I don't really suggest it since its a little buried, i don't know about your team, but mine is very scared when they see shell not to mention when they see something like this: `${arg2:-$arg1}`